# How do I filter array of dictionaries by dictionary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

Here is my JSON.This is for total 250 countries I listed only 3 below. here i need to do the thing is i have the parse the countries into seven different arrays based on continent.

```
{
  "geonames" : [
    {
      "languages" : "ca",
      "east" : 1.786542777831983,
      "continent" : "EU",
      "geonameId" : 3041565,
      "population" : "84000",
      "areaInSqKm" : "468.0",
      "countryName" : "Andorra",
      "south" : 42.42849259876837,
      "countryCode" : "AD",
      "capital" : "Andorra la Vella",
      "isoAlpha3" : "AND",
      "fipsCode" : "AN",
      "isoNumeric" : "020",
      "west" : 1.407186714111276,
      "continentName" : "Europe",
      "north" : 42.65604389629997,
      "currencyCode" : "EUR"
    },
    {
      "languages" : "ar-AE,fa,en,hi,ur",
      "east" : 56.38166046142578,
      "continent" : "AS",
      "geonameId" : 290557,
      "population" : "4975593",
      "areaInSqKm" : "82880.0",
      "countryName" : "United Arab Emirates",
      "south" : 22.63332939147949,
      "countryCode" : "AE",
      "capital" : "Abu Dhabi",
      "isoAlpha3" : "ARE",
      "fipsCode" : "AE",
      "isoNumeric" : "784",
      "west" : 51.58332824707031,
      "continentName" : "Asia",
      "north" : 26.08415985107422,
      "currencyCode" : "AED"
    },
    {
      "languages" : "fa-AF,ps,uz-AF,tk",
      "east" : 74.879448,
      "continent" : "AS",
      "geonameId" : 1149361,
      "population" : "29121286",
      "areaInSqKm" : "647500.0",
      "countryName" : "Afghanistan",
      "south" : 29.377472,
      "countryCode" : "AF",
      "capital" : "Kabul",
      "isoAlpha3" : "AFG",
      "fipsCode" : "AF",
      "isoNumeric" : "004",
      "west" : 60.478443,
      "continentName" : "Asia",
      "north" : 38.483418,
      "currencyCode" : "AFN"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Step 1: parse the JSON into a `NSDictionary with the `NSData` method `JSONObjectWithData`. Step 2: try to figure out how to create the seven arrays by continent. Write your code and if there are problems post the code and ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can filter your `geonames` array. the method `filterArrayByADictionary` gets an array and search criteria and returns filtered array of dictionaries.

```
-(NSArray *)filterArrayByADictionary:(NSArray *)aArray andKey:(NSString *)aPredicte
{
    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:aPredicte];
    return [aArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
}
```

and you can call this method like this.

```
NSArray *AsiaCounties =  [self filterArrayByADictionary: geonames andKey:@"continent = 'AS'"];
NSArray *EuropeCounties =  [self filterArrayByADictionary: geonames andKey:@"continent = 'EU'"];
// rest of the continents...
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you had taken this output in `NSDictionary` :

```
NSDictionary *mainDic;

NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *arrcontinent1 = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *arrcontinent2 = [NSMutableArray new];

arr = [mainDic valueForKey:@"geonames"];

for(int i=0; i<[arr count];i++){
    NSDictionary *dic = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    if([[dic valueForKey:@"continent"] isEqualToString:@"EU"]){
        [arrcontinent1 addObject:dic];
    }
    else if([[dic valueForKey:@"continent"] isEqualToString:@"AS"]){
        [arrcontinent2 addObject:dic];
    }
//        and so on......
}
```