# NSPredicate not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nspredicate

Hey stackoverflow community,
I am having a bit of an issue getting NSPredicate to work as I would like.  I have an array that is being populated from a plist, as well as an array being populated from some Google Places JSON data.  Long story short, I need to check in my plist array if a google place exists.  For this I am using NSPredicate.  My code partially works, for example it will find "McDonalds" in both lists, but fails to find "Jimmy John's".  One thing I noticed is in my plist it is called "Jimmy John's" and in the Google Places API it is called "Jimmy John's Gourmet Sandwiches".  I want it to find this match but it does not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (NSDictionary *jsonname in nameFromJSON)
{
NSPredicate *inBothLists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@, jsonname];
NSArray *arrayFoundInBoth = [nameFromPlist filteredArrayUsingPredicate: inBothLists];
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter array of dictionaries by a dictionary key?

Comment: nameFromJSON is an array that contains the information from google places.  The for loops through each item in the array and checks it using the predicate.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: predicted is ok but couldn't understand your search criteria. Checkout this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839599/how-do-i-filter-array-of-dictionaries-by-dictionary-key/24839788#24839788) it could help.

Comment: I will read through that mohacs, thank you for the reference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this!  My predicate was just fine, the only thing I adjusted is how I was using it.

Before I was using the JSON data to look into the PLIST.  I reversed that and had the PLIST look into the JSON data I pulled down.  This fixed the issue!  Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you filter your data by contain a dictionary data. it mean

```
fiteredObj isEqual: jsonname
```

certainly your code not work
you can try filter your data by name or key

```
for (NSString *jsonname in [nameFromJSON objectForKey:@"nameKey"])
{
NSPredicate *inBothLists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name CONTAINS[c] %@, jsonname];
NSArray *arrayFoundInBoth = [nameFromPlist filteredArrayUsingPredicate: inBothLists];
}
```

Hope it help

Comment: I tried this Huy and get the same result.  It will find McDonalds because the name matches exactly, but it will not find "Jimmy Johns Gourmet Sandwiches".  I can't get it to find that just using 
"Jimmy John's" rather than the full name of Jimmy Johns Gourmet Sandwiches

Comment: "Jimmy John's" and "Jimmy Johns" not the same. so that filteredArray can't work fine. please define exactly name https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Comment: I am sorry I made a typo.  The exact name in PList is "Jimmy John's" the exact name coming from JSON is "Jimmy John's Gourmet Sandwiches".  It should still match that no problem, correct?

Comment: ofcause, you can try another code predicateWithSubstitutionVariables maybe it work :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is right!
SELF is a NSDictionary rather than a NSString,